# How can I add the date axis to my plotly graph object figure?

Tags: python, pandas, keras, plotly, data-visualization

I created a model in keras that predicts the google stock price. I have a plotly graph object figure showing the actual value, train prediction and test prediction.

the problem is that the y axis is already showing the price but the x axis is empty because I didn't know how to use a dataframe column to fill it.

The data's columns are 'Open', 'Close', 'Date', 'Volume', 'High'.

My code is:

```
price = data[['Close']]

def split_data(stock, lookback):
  data_raw = stock.to_numpy()
  data = []

  # Create all possible sequences of length seq_len
  for index in range(len(data_raw)-lookback):
    data.append(data_raw[index: index+lookback])

  data = np.array(data)
  test_set_size = int(np.round(0.2*data.shape[0]))
  train_set_size = data.shape[0] - test_set_size

  x_train = data[:train_set_size,:-1,:]
  y_train = data[:train_set_size,-1,:]
    
  x_test = data[train_set_size:,:-1]
  y_test = data[train_set_size:,-1,:]
    
  return [x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test]

lookback = 20
x_train_keras, y_train_keras, x_test_keras, y_test_keras = split_data(price, lookback)

# Make predictions
test_predict_keras = regression.predict(x_test_keras)

# Invert predictions
train_predict_keras = scaler.inverse_transform(train_predict_keras)
y_train_keras = scaler.inverse_transform(y_train_keras)
test_predict_keras = scaler.inverse_transform(test_predict_keras)
y_test = scaler.inverse_transform(y_test_keras)

# shift train predictions for plotting
trainPredictPlot_keras = np.empty_like(price)
trainPredictPlot_keras[:, :] = np.nan
trainPredictPlot_keras[lookback:len(train_predict_keras)+lookback, :] = train_predict_keras

# shift test predictions for plotting
testPredictPlot_keras = np.empty_like(price)
testPredictPlot_keras[:, :] = np.nan
testPredictPlot_keras[len(train_predict_keras)+lookback-1:len(price)-1, :] = test_predict_keras

original = scaler.inverse_transform(price['Close'].values.reshape(-1,1))

predictions_keras = np.append(trainPredictPlot_keras, testPredictPlot_keras, axis=1)
predictions_keras = np.append(predictions_keras, original, axis=1)
result_keras = pd.DataFrame(predictions_keras)

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(go.Scatter(x=result_keras.index, y=result_keras[0],
                    mode='lines',
                    name='Train prediction')))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=result_keras.index, y=result_keras[1],
                    mode='lines',
                    name='Test prediction'))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(go.Scatter(x=result_keras.index, y=result_keras[2],
                    mode='lines',
                    name='Actual Value')))
fig.update_layout(
    xaxis=dict(
        showline=True,
        showgrid=True,
        showticklabels=False,
        linecolor='white',
        linewidth=2
    ),
    yaxis=dict(
        title_text='Close (USD)',
        titlefont=dict(
            family='Rockwell',
            size=12,
            color='white',
        ),
        showline=True,
        showgrid=True,
        showticklabels=True,
        linecolor='white',
        linewidth=2,
        ticks='outside',
        tickfont=dict(
            family='Rockwell',
            size=12,
            color='white',
        ),
    ),
    showlegend=True,
    template = 'plotly_dark'

)



annotations = []
annotations.append(dict(xref='paper', yref='paper', x=0.0, y=1.05,
                              xanchor='left', yanchor='bottom',
                              text='Results (LSTM)',
                              font=dict(family='Rockwell',
                                        size=26,
                                        color='white'),
                              showarrow=False))
fig.update_layout(annotations=annotations)
fig.show()
```